# Better solution to store data for dll assembly

Tags: c#, dll

I'm developing a dll that is supposed to be commonly used (in nuget for example). Simple description: my DLL simplifies message exchange with a particular service. It allows to send a request, then retrieve a response. Service is asynchronous and it can create a response in a hour or a day after accepting a request, so after making a request my dll calls service every few minutes to check out for response. The problem is that the app that uses the dll can be restarted therefore storing a request queue in memory isn't a good option (I don't want to lose info about requests). Neither is serializing it to file, because I can't know for sure where my dll will be used - it could be pc app, mvc. My main options is: serialize to file, but give an option to set a address where to place serialized files via web/app.config or make a user to think about it. But maybe there is some better solution about how to store requests queue?

Comment: Could you use the %appdata% folder?

Comment: @Chrille So simple? It's good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put theses type of configuration or data files in a subfolder to the [%appdata% folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/318177/what-is-the-appdata-folder-in-windows/). You will have write access to files in this folder and the documentation is extensive. Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/).

in C# you can easily get this folder using:

```
var appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Or use Program Data:

```
var programdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's nice article. I don't think that using appdata in dll that potentially can be used in IIS app (therefore appdata isn't realiable), but programdata folder seems to be a good option.